# Преобразования JQuery кода в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, подскажите как будет выглядеть этот код на чистом JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper').on('click', '.topmenulink', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.topmenulink').removeClass('activelink');
        $( this ).addClass('activelink');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let wraps = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper'),
    links = document.querySelectorAll('.topmenulink');


  wraps.forEach((wrap) => {
    wrap.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      links.forEach((link) => {
        if (!link.classList.contains('activelink')) {
          link.classList.add('activelink');
        } else {
          link.classList.remove('activelink');
        }
      });
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.activelink {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="wrapper">
  wrapper
</a>

<div class="topmenulink">
  topmenulink
</div>
```

Comment: а почему не toggle?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, потому что изменять чей-то код - вандализм! То же касается и при редактировании вопроса, нельзя изменять код. `toggle` не всегда уместен. Практика показала что лучше сразу прописывать условие, возможностей больше.

Comment: HamSter каюсь, понял вас